# Remove Time from date/time vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime, textbox

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()

    Form2.TextBox1.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox2.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox3.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox4.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox5.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox6.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
    Form2.TextBox7.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
```

textbox5 is the one that should only show the date but when i click the button, the textbox shows me the date and time. ex: 12/01/12 12:00 AM.

how can i remove the time from showing up into the textbox?

Answer (score 9):

Since the CurrentCells(4).Value is an object try casting it to a `DateTime` then convert using the [`ToShortDateString Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Form2.TextBox5.Text = CType(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value, DateTime).ToShortDateString
```

or you can use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) which will return true if the conversion is succesfull

```
Dim tempDate As Date
If DateTime.TryParse(CStr(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value), tempDate) Then
    Form2.TextBox5.Text = tempDate.ToShortDateString
Else
    Form2.TextBox5.Text = "Invalid Date"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
If dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value IsNot Nothing
    Form2.TextBox5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/mm/YYYY}", dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value)
Else
    Form2.TextBox5.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: It shows an error: 
Conversion from string "mm/dd/yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Ok... What _is_ the data type of that cell value?

Comment: It is a Date/Time type and im using access as a database

Comment: I only want the date to show in my textbox when i retrieve data from the access database

Comment: So what you're saying is that it's treating null as a date? Why would you tell it to set the contents before you've retrieved a row from the database? If that's tyhe only problem, wrap the Line inside an `If dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value Isnot Nothing` ... `End If` - But this isn't the correct way to do it. You should only be calling the display code once you've got a record to work against

Comment: It may seem wrong but i need to defend my project tomorrow so anything that meets what i need will do. Im just new at programming so excuse my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

there is a datetime format function. check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i already tried the examples from that page but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the .ToString in this line:

```
Form2.TextBox5.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
```

When i removed the .ToString it just shows the short date in the date textbox

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare MyTime as datetime
Mytime  =  dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, Date.now), Date.now)
```